# How can I use Bootstrap datetimepicer as Rails form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I can see the datetimepicker working, but after submit. it won't save to my `Party.time` column

below is my Party model migration code:

```
class CreateParties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :parties do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :user_email
      t.string :description
      t.string :location
      t.datetime :time
      t.datetime :created_at

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

below is what I am struggling:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="time">Time</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="time" name="time"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :time %>
  </div>
```

Below one is working fine.

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :time %><br>
        <%= f.datetime_select :time %>
      </div>
```

**Update**
Time format had to match what is saves into database.

Comment: post sever log @Seong Kim

Comment: I mean I don't know how to pass attribute :time using bootstrap form above

Comment: You need to format the time properly before storing it in parties table, as datepicker format and rails time format will be different. You need to convert them to same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :time, class="control-label", for="time" %>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
            <%= f.datetime_select :time, class="form-control" %>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```